# How to remove all PTX from compiled CUDA to prevent Intellectual Property leaks

Tags: cuda

CUDA PTX is analogous to assembly, and as such reveals the source code.  I have read Section 3.1 of the CUDA Programming Guide and [Section 3.2.7 from the online CUDA compiler documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation).  I have a basic understanding of the -arch versus -code compiler options.

If I understand correctly, specifying -arch compute_XX makes PTX.  Whereas -code sm_XX makes **both** PTX and cubin.

I desire **only** cubin, such that no PTX is in the resulting image.  How can I achieve this?

Preferably via Visual Studio settings, although I only find the -gencode option within Visual Studio Project Settings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PTX is not quite analogous to assembly. PTX is an intermediate representation of the program that can be compiled to the different, incompatible instruction set architectures (ISA) that Nvidia GPUs have been using over time. Usually, a new ISA for Nvidia GPUs comes with an updated version of PTX that can represent the new features of the ISA.

- The `-arch` and `-code` options to `nvcc` [work slightly differently](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#building-for-maximum-compatibility) to what you describe. They are not (mutual exclusive) alternatives, rather they determine different aspects.
  `-arch` controls which PTX version is used as the intermediate representation. As such it is combined with a `compute_XX` PTX version.
  `-code` controls what code is embedded into the resulting  binary - either machine code for the specified ISA if used in the `-code sm_XX` form, or PTX to be just-in-time compiled by the GPU driver if `-code compute_XX` is specified.
  As a special shortcut, specifying *only* `-arch sm_XX` will embed both the compiled code for the specified ISA *and* PTX code into the binary - this probably is the situation that you are referring to that you want to avoid.
  Finally the `-gencode` option allows you to specify multiple `-arch`/`-code` pairs, with the resulting binary containing separate code for each of the pairs.
- You can use [`nvprune`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#nvprune) to remove all but the desired ISA code from a binary.
- If unsure, you can always use [`cuobjdump`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#cuobjdump) to check what is in a specific binary.

So the way to prevent any PTX code from being present in your resulting binary is to call nvcc as `nvcc -arch compute_XX -code sm_XX` (or use multiple such pairs together with `-gencode`).

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening answer.  It helps to understand that PTX is a required intermediate.  Then the statement in my question is wrong; -code sm_XX does not make both PTX+cubin, it makes only cubin.

Comment: @TysonHilmer Just to point out the obvious: Code can be reverse engineered from a binary representation as well via a process of disassembly (that is, converting binary code into the equivalent assembly language instructions) and annotation. In the x86 and ARM worlds there are very powerful tools available to assist with that task, so this is a platform-independent phenomenon. I am not aware of similar tools for GPU code, but with a bit of practice, one can certainly decipher SASS code. So all you are doing by removing PTX is discouraging casual code readers, not determined attackers.